# Execute raw JSON request using NEST / Elasticsearch.Net

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Some (advanced) requests are easier to write in pure JSON than using the syntax NEST provides.
There is a `CreatePostAsync` in the `IElasticLowLevelClient` interface but that uses the `Index` API specifically.

I don't want to use a `HttpClient` directly because then I'm missing features like [maximum retries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/maximum-retries-per-request.html) etc.

Is it possible to do *any* request to Elasticsearch (`GET`, `POST` etc) using the NEST / Elasticsearch.Net client?

Comment: Are you talking about sending literal json? The low-level client calls for all actions take json formatted string, see here for an example https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7e94f527acfb3ebc7f6ea4b27b3d59a9139b6e2e/src/Tests/Tests.Reproduce/GithubIssue2886.cs

Comment: @sramalingam24 Yes, for my `_reindex` example something like `ReindexAsync<StringResponse>(PostData.String("my-json")` on the LowLevel client would work indeed, thanks!

Comment: Cool, no problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to make *any* request, you can use `DoRequest/DoRequestAsync` on the low level client

```
var lowLevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient();

var stringResponse = lowLevelClient.DoRequest<StringResponse>(
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    "_search", 
    PostData.Serializable(new
    {
        query = new { match_all = new { } }
    }));
```

Also exposed on the high level client, NEST, in the `.LowLevel` property

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var stringResponse = client.LowLevel.DoRequest<StringResponse>(
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    "_search", 
    PostData.Serializable(new
    {
        query = new { match_all = new { } }
    }));
```

Comment: This would be nice to use for non built-in commands on the LowLevel client, thanks!

Comment: @Kapé the aim with the low level client is to implement all non-experimental APIs. Sometimes the client can trail Elasticsearch so APIs are not yet implemented, but was there a specific API you were looking for?

Comment: At this moment I only need the `_reindex` API, but I didn't notice the methods on the LowLevel client allowing you to put in JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NEST, you can use the `Raw` query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/raw-query-usage.html

> Allows a query represented as a string of JSON to be passed to NEST’s
>   Fluent API or Object Initializer syntax. This can be useful when
>   porting over a query expressed in the query DSL over to NEST.

You should be able to do something like:

```
query.Raw(yourJsonQueryString)
```

**EDIT:**
If you are looking to do a `_reindex` you can use the reindex API.

```
var reindexResponse = client.ReindexOnServer(r => r
    .Source(s => s
        .Index("old-index")
    )
    .Destination(d => d
        .Index("new-index")
    )
    .WaitForCompletion(true)
);
```

Comment: That's only for querying (searching) as far as I can see, I'm looking to do any request like doing a `POST _reindex` using just JSON